# ImageButton is Null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an ImageButton in a fragment that is opened by a TabLayout in my main activity. When I try to get a reference to the ImageButton in my main activity inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)`:

```
 playPauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
```

it returns as null. The fragment that encloses my ImageButton looks like this:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/play_pause"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
```

Any ideas on why this returns null?

Comment: Because it resides in your Fragment's layout and not in the Activity's. And `findViewById` is called on the Activity's layout. Why should you access the button from the Activity anyway? Access it in Fragment and set the appropriate actions on it.

Comment: Initiate it in fragment, and then setOnClickListener in fragment itself

Comment: I think you should use the `inflater` from the Fragment's `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) ` in order to extract your fragment's view.

Comment: Probably because fragments work async, thats why you need to bind your view in your fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the view inside a fragment from the MainActivity directly like this as its not a view included in it, it included in the fragment, so you have to get it from within the fragment itself after it has been created(i.e in the `onViewCreated()` method) and with the instance of the view created for the fragment:

```
 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     // Declaring the View you want
     ImageButton play_pause = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause);

 }
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I thought because the fragment was loaded into the activity I'd be able to do that.

Comment: you are so welcome, I'm happy I could help in solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

get reference like this by using **getView()**

```
 playPauseButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you extends `Fragment` means should use like,

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_FILE_NAME, container, false);
    ImageButton playPauseButton = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause);


    return view;

}
```

This may helps you